# How to copy shape format

Tags: format, copy, visual-paradigm

I'm using Visual Paradigm to draw my use-cases diagrams.

For nicer presentation, I want my all my use-cases to have the same shape. Instead of resizing them manually, I want to use the format copier to achieve this.

I followed the steps as explained here : https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/1283/33/26921_formatcopier.html

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

Tested method:

1. Left-Click on the shape I want to copy format.
2. Left-Click on the "Format Copier" button in the menubar.
3. Left-Click on the use-case I want to apply copied format.

(Here's a short clip showing the manipulation : https://i.gyazo.com/41462b8cc0b4114be8c6ebe490fadab3.mp4)

It doesn't change anything and simply select the new shape I clicked without reformatting anything.

Is there another way to do this ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format copier is specific for copy the "styles and formatting" information, which are the fonts, foreground and background styles. For the size you can select multiple shapes on diagram then mouse over your selection to bring up the resource icons for setting the size of multiple elements at once.

[image]